# Android: Check if bitmap has aspect ratio 4:3

Tags: android, bitmap

I am retrieving images from gallery using Content resolver

```
  final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            Cursor imagecursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                    null, orderBy);
            int image_column_index = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);


    count = imagecursor.getCount();
            imageList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

  imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                context.getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
    imageList.add(b);

    }
```

How do I check if the bitmaps aspect ratio is 4:3 and then add to arraylist?

Comment: b.getWidth() and b.getHeight() ? But does the thumbnail have the same aspect ratio?

Comment: @greenapps i got the problem..i don't know why, but for all images, I am getting 96.0 as width and 96.0 as height

Comment: Indeed. I already suggested that: `But does the thumbnail have the same aspect ratio ? ` as the original? Get the original i would say or not the MICRO_KIND.

Comment: Or better add as collumns `MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH` and `MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT`.

Comment: yaa i got it!! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to check bitmap's width and height.

```
float RATIO = 4 / 3;
float EPSILON = 0.00001f;
float ratio = (float)bitmap.getWidth() / bitmap.getHeight();
if (Math.abs(ratio - RATIO) < EPSILON) {
    list.add(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: i am getting (Math.abs(ratio - RATIO) as 0.0 for all images, even for those images whose height is greater than width

Comment: Make ratio a float. And cast width and heigth to float in the division. `float ratio = (float)bitmap.getWidth() / (float)bitmap.getHeight();`

Comment: @greenapps: Is Math.abs needed ?

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: in this  answer he has given a conditon `if (Math.abs(ratio - RATIO) < EPSILON) `

Comment: Yes i knew. But why are you asking?

Comment: because still the condition was satisfying for all images

Comment: Did you implement the floats? Dont let us guess. Noone would satisfy if all are 96x96.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if ((double) b.getHeight() / b.getWidth() == (double) 4 / 3) {
                    // ratio is 4:3, now you can add to ArrayList
                } else {
                    // ratio is not 4:3
                }
```

Comment: This is not work in some situation. Don't use equalality operator with floats and doubles. This link may help -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/CompareOfFloatsByEqualityOperator.html